# new to coding, need help fixing html/css wireframe

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding, this is my first week in my Fullstack course and we have some homework that I've been working on for a while now. I've managed to get my wireframe to look similar to the homework example (we're supposed to make it look the same) and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this html/css code.

Also, I'm not sure exactly how else to show what I am working on other than posting the majority of my css, so i apologize if I do this wrong.

:)

I've placed red borders around the content I'm attempting to align evenly on all sides. I've tried changing the padding, margins, float positions, width (all that I know that would adjust the box(es), but I still cannot seem to get the "aside" content to align with the rest of the wireframe objects.

`````HTML````

````
        <header class="main-head">
            <p>header</p>
        </header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <nav>nav</nav>
        <div class="divCont">
                <div class="aside1">
                        <aside>aside</aside>
                </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <article class="sect1">section
                                <p class="art1">article</p>
                                <div class="inside1">
                                        <h3>h1, h2, h3</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="paraCont">
                                        <p class="para1">p</p>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <footer>footer</footer>
 ```   </div>
````

`````````external css```````````````````

```
body {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #777;
    text-align: center;
}

div.layout {
    width: 495px;
}

/* left section */
.sect1 {
    padding: 2%;
    width: 100%;
}

/* right section */
div.aside1 {
    margin-left: 100px;
    border: solid red;
    padding: 2%;
    color: #777;
    width: 200px;
    height: 165px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;}

article {
    color:#777;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}

div.divCont {
    border: solid red;
}

/* article box */
.art1 {
    width: 60%;
    color: #ebebeb;
    background-color: #777;
}

/* h1,h2,h3 box */
.inside1 {
    width: 60%;
    color: #ebebeb;
    background-color: #777;
}

/* para box */
p.para1 {
    width: 60%;
    color:#ebebeb;
    background-color: #777;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #777;
  text-align: center;
}

div.layout {
  width: 495px;
}


/* left section */

.sect1 {
  padding: 2%;
  width: 100%;
}


/* right section */

div.aside1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  border: solid red;
  padding: 2%;
  color: #777;
  width: 200px;
  height: 165px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
}

article {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

div.divCont {
  border: solid red;
}


/* article box */

.art1 {
  width: 60%;
  color: #ebebeb;
  background-color: #777;
}


/* h1,h2,h3 box */

.inside1 {
  width: 60%;
  color: #ebebeb;
  background-color: #777;
}


/* para box */

p.para1 {
  width: 60%;
  color: #ebebeb;
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <header class="main-head">
    <p>header</p>
  </header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <nav>nav</nav>
  <div class="divCont">
    <div class="aside1">
      <aside>aside</aside>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <article class="sect1">section
          <p class="art1">article</p>
          <div class="inside1">
            <h3>h1, h2, h3</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="paraCont">
            <p class="para1">p</p>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

this is what I'm trying to do - https://gyazo.com/6f27f40e4f3e75831b5e4728387ea11f

this is what I've done so far - https://gyazo.com/79299a16a0eb2208db98519005b3bf9d

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick edit. Also your link tag should be above  in  tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #777;
    text-align: center;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.aside1 {
width: 49%;
float: left;
height: 165px;

}
.aside2 {
width: 49%;
float: right;
height: 165px;

}

article {
    background-color:green;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 5px
}

footer {
width: 100%;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
 <header class="main-head">
        <p>header</p>
 </header>
 <nav>nav</nav>
        <section class="divCont">
                <div class="aside1">
                        <p>Section</p>
                        <article>
                        Article
                        <div style="background-color:white; margin: 5px;">
                        H1,h2,H3
                        </div>
                        <div style="background-color:yellow;margin: 5px; ">
                        p
                        </div>
                        </article>
                 </div>
                 <div class="aside2">
                 Aside
                 </div>

          </section>



 <footer> Footer </footer>
</body>
</html>
```